# mysql query does not work with where clause and variable

Tags: php, mysqli

i'm trying to get data from table using mysql where clause. but it does not return any value or error.

here is the function

```
function getMsgByName($sender){
        global $connection;
        $sender  = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$sender);

        $query = "SELECT Message FROM chat WHERE Sender ='$sender'";
        $run = mysqli_query($connection,$query);
        $messages = array();
        while($message = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run)){
            $messages[] = array('message'=>$message['Message']);
        }
        return $messages;

    }
```

Comment: @wp78de no i want to get data from database table. not from array

Comment: Try to echo the $query variable and see what it returns. You can also run that query in your database and see what it gives you.